# Category id filter to Magento 2 products collection

Tags: magento2

I want to add category id filter to Magento 2 product collection but it doesn't filter the collection in required manner. I am trying in below way:

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog_category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left')
            ->addFieldToFilter('category_id', ['nin' => 25]);
```

I don't want any product from category id 25 to be included in collection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
addCategoriesFilter(['nin' => $categories]);
```

Code

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
$collection->addCategoriesFilter(['nin' => 25]);
```

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: I found an issue at my end, my code was also working fine but same product id was assigned to another category too. So it was loading in collection. Anyways thanks for your support @userpk :)